# What HBRUSH to use for Internet Explorer Toolbar Background?

Tags: c++, internet-explorer

[image]
The color (#E6EFFA) is circled in red.

I am trying to make an Internet Explorer Toolbar which matches IE's UI.  What `HBRUSH` should I use to get that color? I tried looking through the various standard HBRUSHs (0 to 31) and did not find any that matched the color, never mind one that was the "right" one.  I am not what the proper way to look that color up is; presumably hardcoding it is a bad idea.

Comment: Did you try `GetSysColor(COLOR_MENUBAR)`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724371(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @jeffamaphone : `COLOR_MENUBAR` gives me #F0F0F0 .

Comment: Well, it's got to be one of the COLOR_* guys.

Comment: @jeffamaphone: I tried all of them.  It isn't.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to *create* such a brush is via `CreateSolidBrush(color)`. The comment from jeffamaphone is correct; `GetSysColor(ID)` is the proper way to get standard colors.